# how is React executing this specific code

Tags: reactjs

I learn React and I found this [codesandbox by mimimimichael](https://codesandbox.io/s/o4joypm7j6?file=/src/index.js:1202-1207).

And I wonder after trying to find answers elsewhere:

1. When is `let Items = addItems();` executed? Does React read the file from top-bottom?
2. does it matter what the filename is where this code run in or is React looking for the `ReactDOM.render`..?
3. How does React know to call the `function addItems(amount = 10)` from `addItems(20)` and not to call the local `addItems()`?
4. Does `function addItems(amount = 10)` means that if no argument is passed default is 10?
5. Is this really advisable to organize code like this. I mean the `PlaceholderImages` wraps up the hole file and have `App` backed inside like that

and see this Class now:

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import Masonry from "./Masonry";
import VerticalMasonry from "./VerticalMasonry";
import { sample, uniqueId } from "lodash";
import PlaceholderImages from "./PlaceholderImages";
import ItemRenderer from "./ItemRenderer";

PlaceholderImages().then(images => {
  function addItems(amount = 10) {
    return new Array(amount).fill("").map(i => {
      const id = uniqueId();
      const image = sample(images);

      const width = 480;
      const height = Math.round((480 / image.width) * image.height);
      const imageUrl = `https://picsum.photos/${width}/${height}?image=${
        image.id
      }`;

      return {
        id,
        key: id,
        ratio: 1 / (image.width / image.height),
        backgroundImage: `url(${imageUrl})`,
        background: `rgb(${Math.ceil(Math.random() * 256)}, ${Math.ceil(
          Math.random() * 256
        )}, ${Math.ceil(Math.random() * 256)})`,
        title: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet",
        description:
          "At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet."
      };
    });
  }

  let Items = addItems();

  class App extends React.Component {
    state = {
      columns: 3,
      items: Items,
      gutter: 16,
      outerGutter: true,
      debug: true,
      vertical: true
    };

    addItems() {
      this.setState({
        items: this.state.items.concat(addItems(20))
      });
    }

    render() {
      const {
        items,
        width,
        gutter,
        outerGutter,
        debug,
        vertical,
        fullscreen
      } = this.state;

      const LeComponent = vertical ? Masonry : VerticalMasonry;

      return (
        <div>
          <div
            style={{
              position: fullscreen && "absolute",
              zIndex: 2
            }}
          >
            <label htmlFor="gutter">Gutter</label>
            <input
              id="gutter"
              type="number"
              step={1}
              min={0}
              max={32}
              value={gutter}
              onChange={e => {
                this.setState({
                  gutter: parseInt(e.target.value)
                });
              }}
            />
            <button
              onClick={() => this.setState({ outerGutter: !outerGutter })}
            >
              Outer Gutter: {outerGutter ? "On" : "Off"}
            </button>
            <button onClick={() => this.setState({ debug: !debug })}>
              debug
            </button>
            <button onClick={() => this.setState({ vertical: !vertical })}>
              {vertical ? "Vertical" : "Horizontal"}
            </button>
            <button onClick={() => this.setState({ width: 360 })}>360</button>
            <button onClick={() => this.setState({ width: 480 })}>480</button>
            <button onClick={() => this.setState({ width: 640 })}>640</button>
            <button onClick={() => this.setState({ width: 728 })}>728</button>
            <button onClick={() => this.setState({ width: 960 })}>960</button>
            <button onClick={() => this.setState({ width: "100%" })}>
              100%
            </button>
            <button onClick={() => this.setState({ fullscreen: !fullscreen })}>
              {fullscreen ? "Fullscreen off" : "Fullscreen on"}
            </button>
          </div>
          <div
            style={{
              width,
              height: !fullscreen && 600,
              position: fullscreen ? "initial" : "relative",
              margin: "0 auto"
            }}
          >
            <LeComponent
              infinite
              items={items}
              itemRenderer={ItemRenderer}
              gutter={gutter}
              outerGutter={outerGutter}
              extraPx={0}
              debug={debug}
              rows={{
                0: 1,
                320: 2,
                480: 3,
                640: 4
              }}
              cols={{
                0: 1,
                360: 2,
                640: 2,
                960: 3,
                1280: 4,
                1400: 5,
                1720: 6,
                2040: 7,
                2360: 8
              }}
              onEnd={() => {
                this.addItems();
              }}
            />
            <style>
              {`body {
                background-color:  white;
              }`}
            </style>
          </div>
        </div>
      );
    }
  }

  const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
  ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In javascript, the code invoked from top to down. if code is sync, the code in the upper line completely done and next line invoked. but if you use async function, code invoked, but it doesn't mean the change is applied in same time.
suppose you call async function in line 1 for calculating sum. if process of calculating make 5 second, and before this time you use result, result is not correct.
for this scenario, you have two option

1. using async as sync by using await before async function.
2. using callback function like `then` in your code.

option 2 means when calculating has been done, print it in screen, but don't wait for calculation.
`PlaceholderImages()` is async function and has callback function named addItems.
addItems is function defined and executed as callback function of `PlaceholderImages()`.

The code  `let Items = addItems();` invoke the following:

```
function addItems(amount = 10) {
    return new Array(amount).fill("").map(i => {
      const id = uniqueId();
      const image = sample(images);

      const width = 480;
      const height = Math.round((480 / image.width) * image.height);
      const imageUrl = `https://picsum.photos/${width}/${height}?image=${
        image.id
      }`;

      return {
        id,
        key: id,
        ratio: 1 / (image.width / image.height),
        backgroundImage: `url(${imageUrl})`,
        background: `rgb(${Math.ceil(Math.random() * 256)}, ${Math.ceil(
          Math.random() * 256
        )}, ${Math.ceil(Math.random() * 256)})`,
        title: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet",
        description:
          "At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet."
      };
    });
  }
```

and the code

```
addItems() {
      this.setState({
        items: this.state.items.concat(addItems(20))
      });
    }
```

is accessible only inside of app

but `addItems` this line of code `items: this.state.items.concat(addItems(20))` invoke her parent. because parent function has arg.

and about this part `amount = 10`, yes it's default value for when amount is not passed to function.

the filename is not important and also ReactDOM.render does not looking for enything.
i advise you too prevent coding like this.
this part of code is bad smell and violation of solid principles.

Comment: Thanks excellent answer I like the SOLID principle especially "S" that's why I asked